# Problem with Windows Authentication and delegation In Web connected to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, kerberos, windows-authentication, delegation

Here is my scenario:

- Website is a .NET MVC web on ServerA using IIS and Windows Authentication (impersonating AppPool user into current domain account).
- WCF Service is on ServerB, also with Windows Authentication (and checking the impersonated user is a valid one inside the system).

Both servers are on the same domain.

When I'm inside ServerA, and I enter the Website using localhost, everything goes fine. The request reaches Website, we impersonate, send the request to WCF, and it is properly receiving the request from the impersonated user WindowsIdentity.

But it is not working when I'm outside ServerA, and I enter the Website using the server name address. The request reaches Webside, we successfully impersonate the user, send the request to WCF... and it is blocked due to an anonymous logon:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: The service does not allow you to log on anonymously.
```

Things we have already tried or set up:

- On IIS, ASP.NET impersonation is enabled and 'Negotiate' is on top of the Windows Authentication Providers
- The AppPool user has delegation configured (both Constrained and Unconstrained). Furthermore, the 'Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)' is enabled.
- On the Local Policies, the AppPool user is added into 'Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation'.
- On Web.config, added the following section:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="#">
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" name="CommissionServiceEndpoint" bindingNamespace="#" contract="#" />
        <endpoint address="mex" bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your code, `bindingConfiguration` = `bindingName`.

```
<endpoint address="" 
          bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding" name="CommissionServiceEndpoint" bindingNamespace="#" contract="#" />
```